# how to use request.form by the id of element not by nam in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, radio-button

I have some radio button in a fieldset which have the same name
 that one can be choosen at a time
how can access them in code by id not name because all of them have the same name

```
          <fieldset id="group1">
            <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="google" checked runat="server" value ="google"/>
            <label for="google" id="Label1">1th  SE</label>
            <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="yahoo" runat="server" value ="yahoo"/>
            <label for="yahoo">2th SE</label>

            <input type="radio" name="group1" id="bing" runat="server" value ="bing" />
            <label for="searchSite" id="Label2">3th SE</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="ask" runat="server" value ="ask" />
            <label for="ask">4th SE
            </label>
            <input type="radio" name="group1"  id="mse" runat="server" value ="mse" />
            <label for="ask">5th SE
            </label>

           </fieldset>
```

Comment: Is your HTML code for the form/radio button classified?

Comment: i added html code

Answer (score 0):

If you use just HTML elements `Request.Form["group1"]` should work for you. It will return the `value` of the selected option: google, yahoo, etc